# Can not create type for index in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am putting the following in kibana dev tools

```
PUT college/students/st1
{
  "name":"Rahul Kumar",
  "roll":71418
}
```

But i am getting - `bad request`

It is mentioned in the document that we can create index and types within that index.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_indexing_employee_documents.html

[image]

But i am not able to create type within index.

ES Version - latest as of now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you're looking at is obsolete, The Elasticsearch Definitive Guide was made for ES 5.x.

[Mapping types have been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) in ES 8.x, the correct way to do it is like this now:

```
PUT college/_doc/st1
{
  "name":"Rahul Kumar",
  "roll":71418
}
```